# Use for loop to display array in HTML tables without duplicating

Tags: html

I am trying to write a simple product management program. Basically, when users input a product name, it will be saved to an array and displayed on the table using a for loop.

I am having trouble with my codes here. It shows duplicate each time I click add a product. For example, the 1st time I add `productA`, it shows `productA`. The second time I add `productB`, it shows `productA`, `productA`, `productB` (duplicate `productA`).

I know the problem is within the loop I use, but have no idea how to fix.

I cannot paste HTML code here, but here is the link to my codes. https://github.com/minhle0105/functionPractice/tree/main/productManagement

Thanks everyone

Comment: you can add your code in the code snippet option on the editor. I have done that in my answer. I created a snippet and copied the code from your GitHub before debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

You were displaying products array instead of the new product, that's what it was displaying the whole array.
TRY This

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <head>
            <title>Product List Management</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      </head>
      <body>
            <p>Add New Product</p>
            <div class="add_product">  
                  <input type="text" name="productAdd" id="productAdd" placeholder="New Product">
                  <button type="button" id="addbtn" onclick="addProductToList()">Add</button>
            </div>
            <p>Display All Products</p>
            <div class="productDisplay" id="productDisplay">
                  <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                              <tr>
                                    <th style="text-align: left; background-color: white;">Product Names</th>
                              </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="result">
                        </tbody>
                  </table>

            </div>
            
            <script>
                  let products = [];
                  let count = 0;
                  function addProductToList() {
                        let productAdd = document.getElementById("productAdd").value;
                        products.push(productAdd);
                          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML ="";
                        displayProduct(products)
                  }
                  
                  function displayProduct(products) {
                        
                        for(let i=0; i<products.length; i++){
                            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML +=`<tr>
                              <td>${i+1}</td>
                              <td>${products[i]}</td>
                              <td><button type="button" class="btn edit">Edit</button></td>
                              <td><button type="button" class="btn delete">Delete</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        `
                         }         
                     
                  }

            </script>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a homework and I am required to use a for loop to display the product in the list. Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: I have edited my answer to use a for loop. let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```js
 let products = [];
                  let count = 0;
                  function addProductToList() {
                        let productAdd = document.getElementById("productAdd").value;
                        products.push(productAdd);
           document.getElementById("productAdd").value='';              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML ="";
                        displayProduct(products)
                  }
                  
                  function displayProduct(products) {
                       
                    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
 
                            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML +=`<tr>
                                         <td>${products[i]}</td>
                              
                        </tr>
                        `
                         }         
                     
                  }
```

```html
 <div class="add_product">  
                  <input type="text" name="productAdd" id="productAdd" placeholder="New Product" required>
                  <button type="button" id="addbtn" onclick="addProductToList()">Add</button>
            </div>
         
            <div class="productDisplay" id="productDisplay"  style="margin-top: 15px;">
                  <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                              <tr>
                                    <th>Product</th>
                              </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="result">
                        </tbody>
                  </table>

            </div>
```